# Say me out loud, I'll get stronger

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> Say me out loud
>   I’ll get stronger
>   Rearrange me
>   It will just make me larger
>
> I’m triangular and angular
>   Can be turned into one
>   Left a whisper
>   While staring down
>
> Had a groovy body
>   Needle very small
>   I was briefly with Jordan
>   Though more in Football
>
> Just look at me
>   I’m a weapon with a horse
>   Guess who I am
>   Do you have the nerves?

Inspired by a puzzle on this site but if I reference it, the answer will be easy. So I will do so after the answer is in.

Hint

> I am associated with Trump too

Hint 2

> Inspired by a great puzzle by @hexomino

Comment: Is it rot13(jnyy) :)

Comment: No @Danhill. I will keep giving more clues.

Comment: Ah, I thought the style seemed familiar (thank you for the nod). Unfortunately, I do not yet know the answer but will think on it.

Comment: Is the answer "Hiaaaaah", as if I recall correctly Goku did that and he is stronger than ever :?

Comment: No @athin. Look at hexomino's popular puzzle that will be a big clue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A half right turn is

> 45 or forty-five

Say me out loud, I’ll get stronger

> fortify, when spoken, which is to make stronger. Credit to Stiv.

Rearrange me, It will just make me larger

> forty-five anagrammed is *over fifty*, per DEEM's [What number is that ? Asks Grandpa](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98175/what-number-is-that-asks-grandpa)

I’m triangular and angular

> 45 is a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), a 45 degree angle is acute and common as it's half a right angle

Can be turned into one, Left a whisper, While staring down

> TBD

Had a groovy body, Needle very small

> a single's record, named from its rotational speed of 45 rpm

I was briefly with Jordan

> after retiring from the Bulls, Michael Jordan wore the 45 jersey for the Birmingham Barons

Though more in Football

> a football match is two halves of 45 minutes each

Just look at me, I’m a weapon with a horse

> .45 is a common gun calibre, as in the 45 Colt which is a horse

Guess who I am, Do you have the nerves?

> 45, and nerves to post a partial

Hint 1

> I am associated with Trump too - the 45th president of the USA

Hint 2

> Inspired by a great puzzle by @hexomino - the super [An untouchable time traveller](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/79602/an-untouchable-time-traveller)

Comment: I think this is it, but I don't see where "half right turn" comes from -- that's not in the puzzle!

Comment: @shoover, this is totally indebted to your https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/98194/19547, the "half right turn", is just saying my go is half done, and turn is the attempt, it's half 90.

Comment: Nice :) +1 for the spot. I think the 'get stronger' part concerns the word's resemblance to rot13(SBEGVSL be SBEGVSVRQ) specifically...

Comment: @Stiv, ah that's it! Thank you, I will update.

Comment: Great answer, +1.

Comment: @hexomino, I had thought this puzzle was based on a type of yours which clue a word before, between and after other words, and I really enjoy those. It was only after DEEM altered me that I checked your most upvoted question on which this is based.

Comment: @Tom yes, I thought exactly as you did, the wording was very deceptive.

Comment: @Tom  45 is a cut from Band Shinedown. Check it out. GREAT LYRICS. American Football has 45 players. And an amazing tidbit: There are 45 miles of Nerves in human body!

Comment: Also @Tom  Tan45 = One

Answer (score 4):

SPECULATIVE PARTIAL ANWSER:

I think the answer is inspired by:

> [A short, brutal riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20233/a-short-brutal-riddle)

this answer is not meant to offend anyone and I'm not sure about this anwser

the answer is

> fake news
>  
>
>  since fake news is sometimes real and sometimes fake, in each stanza the first half is real and the second half is fake.

Say me out loud.
I’ll get stronger

> when you spread fake news, it become stronger

Rearrange me
It will just make me larger

> when you rearrange fake news, you get "weakens" which is the opposite of larger.

...not sure about the middle...

Comment: oops accidentally posted.. still working on it