# What number is that ? Asks Grandpa

Tags: riddle, mathematics, no-computers, english, anagram

"So here is a number between 1 and 60" Says Grandpa

"If you take its WORD anagram and subtract this number you will get

> Anagram of the number - number > 5

What is that number"?

"So it is the anagram of the spelling of the number?" I asked

"Yes, son. Think"

Post script

I see a lot of Fractions as answers. There is a simple integer solution. No Fraction.

Comment: Noting the absence of the 'language' tag, I'm guessing Grandpa's only interested in English words for numbers?

Comment: That is right @Stiv

Comment: Considering the accepted answer, you can't really put *that* into a mathematical equation. You already *mostly* wrote it out in words (which would loosen up the allowable inputs a bit), so I would suggest just finishing that sentence, i.e. "... you will get a number greater than 5" and removing the equation.

Comment: This is quite brilliant, why not ask a generalization to other languages? (e.g. *What is the smallest number in each language L having the property that its anagram is also (objectively) a legitimate number or numerical quantity in that language?*)

Comment: Here's the [Multiilanguage generalization of “What number is that? Asks Grandpa”](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98238/multiilanguage-generalization-of-what-number-is-that-asks-grandpa)

Comment: Thanks for asking @smic. I am thrilled with the answers to your question

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Grandpa is thinking of

> 45

because

> FORTY-FIVE

anagrams to

> OVER FIFTY

and

> OVER FIFTY minus FORTY-FIVE yields over five.

Comment: This sounds right. I like it. +1

Comment: I agree with MacGyver88, this really explains the lower bound. +1

Comment: @Tom   abj pna lbh thrff gur nafjre gb gur cerivbhf dhrfgvba: Fnl zr bhg ybhq V jvyy trg fgebatre?

Comment: @DEEM, oh I see, but not all the answers, I may post a try!

Answer (score 16):

<sup>**NB This answer was given when the first line of the puzzle read: *"So here is a number below 60" Says Grandpa* - since then a further stipulation has been added to restrict the number further to 'between 1 and 60'...**</sup>

I note that Grandpa hasn't specified that the number must be:

> *greater than 0* - just that it has to be "below 60".

To this end, I propose that Grandpa might be thinking of:

> **MINUS SEVENTY-SIX** (-76)

Its anagram is then:

> **MINUS SIXTY-SEVEN** (-67)

and the calculation works out as:

> -67 - (-76) = -67 + 76 = 9

which is indeed larger than 5...!

Comment: I am sorry @Stiv. I should have written that it is between 0 to 60. MY BAD

Comment: @DEEM Aw, that's a shame - I thought I had it! :)

Comment: MY apology. Not thinking straight. Your way it could be -79 and -69 also right?

Comment: @DEEM Not quite - the first digit has to be the larger of the two to end up with a difference greater than positive 5 when the number is taken from its anagram. My way, it could be any of -76, -86, -87, -96, -97 or -98 (if we restrict ourselves to just two-digit negative numbers) - I chose -76 as the largest of all the possibilities.

Comment: Actually, the ones involving an 8 wouldn't work, since you only add a 'y' when it's in the tens place, and the other digits add a "ty", so they won't anagram properly.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman That's a fair point - so re my comment above, it would actually only be for -76, -96 and -97 in double digits.

Answer (score 14):

Ok thinking outside the box...

The number could be

> One

Since

> Eon - One > 5
>  Since an eon is a really big number (can be 1 Billion or just a really impossibly long measure of time) that minus 1 is always greater than 5

Comment: Wow. Great out of the box thinking @Bee. +1  Grandpa had another number in mind

Answer (score 11):

Oh boy, here I go swiping again:

The number is

> Fifty-sevenths, $\frac{50}{7}$, and its anagram is seventy-fifths, $\frac{70}{5}$.

The difference is

> $\frac{70}{5}-\frac{50}{7} = \frac{490-250}{35} = \frac{240}{35}= \frac{48}{7} = 6 \frac{6}{7} > 5$.

**Second Try**

I’m going to use

> an incorrect (obsolete) spelling of forty, namely fourty, to get fourty-six and sixty-four (64-46=18).....

Comment: Wow. OK. But there is a simple integer number @El-Guest

Comment: Outside of using an incorrect spelling for forty (ie. fourty), I’m not seeing any integers with anagrams... @DEEM

Comment: Boy you are so close @El Guest

Comment: @DEEM is my second attempt correct?

Comment: Regarding that second attempt, then the answer is no longer unique, no?

Comment: Yes, but the initial question never asked for a unique answer — up to DEEM, really!

Comment: Spelling is important. Forty is the MW dictionary spelling

Comment: Thank goodness, that would’ve been a copout of an answer

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps the integer between 1 and 60 is

> 50, or as Grandpa calls it, three hundred and fifty sevenths

the anagram of the number - number > 5

> three hundred and seventy fifths - 50 = 74 - 50 = 24

I upvoted El-Guest's [answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/50778/el-guest) and it may have been sniped !

Comment: it took me a while, I was thinking that rot13(guerr uhaqerq naq svsgl friragu jnf guerr uhaqerq naq (svsgl friragu))

Comment: @melfnt, NP - I hoped there being no hyphen between the last two words made this ok. Still, serves me right trying to snipe, shoover's answer is better.

Answer (score 4):

> 46 and 64
>  Fourty Six and Sixty Four
>  64 - 46 = 18 > 5

Comment: Think I ninjaed you if this is correct, but nice guess!

Comment: I think you were just pipped to this suggestion by @El-Guest by about 5 minutes - bad luck! But welcome to Puzzling :)

Comment: Yes. It was based on @El-Guest's finding. No denying. :)

Comment: Spelling is important!  Forty is the correct spelling

Comment: @DEEM..So this is not the correct answer??

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if this qualifies for anagram, still the difference is too low

> the number could be $\frac{50}6$ with anagram `sixty fifth'. The difference is $\frac{60}5-\frac{50}6 = 3.66..$'

Comment: But is it > 5??