# Probabilities for "What number is that? — asks grandpa"

Tags: mathematics, optimization, probability, letters

<sub>Inspired from [Multilanguage generalization of "What number is that? Asks Grandpa"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/98238/51928) and [What number is that ? Asks Grandpa](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/98175/51928)</sub>

---

In this puzzle we will use the English alphabet of 26 letters. We create a language that uses it and we call it $LANG$. Previously in [What number is that ? Asks Grandpa](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/98175/51928) the issue was:

> What is the smallest positive integer $N$ for which:
> If you take its WORD anagram and subtract the number $N$ itself, you get some positive integer quantity.
> **Anagram of the number** - **Number** > 0"?

- Hence the smallest legal number in English would be 67 — **SIXTY-SEVEN**—  since 76 — **SEVENTY-SIX** — is also a legal number, and 76 - 67 is positive.

#### For $LANG$ things are quite different as each number is written this way:

1. $0$ can not be written in $LANG$.
2. $i>0$ written in $LANG$ is at least of length $i$.
3. $i>0$ written in $LANG$ is of length $i+k$ with $0 \le k\le i$ with probablity $\dfrac{1}{i+1}$.
4. All letters of any $i>0$ written in $LANG$ are equally randomly drawn from the English alphabet. Each letter having a probability of $\dfrac{1}{26}$ to be drawn.

#### Example $i=3$

2. $i$ will be composed by $3$ letters at least.
3. $i$ will be composed by $3$ letters with probability $\dfrac1{i+3}=\dfrac14$. $i$ could also be composed of $4$, $5$, or $6$ letters with the same probability of $0.25$.
4. If after a first draw, $i$ was to be of length $4$, $i$ could be: $aaaa$ or $love$ both with probability $\dfrac{1}{26^4}\simeq 0.0000022$.

### Puzzle

You have the choice to select $N > 0$ such that you will have a draw on $I=\{1,\dots ,N\}$. There is a success if and only if there is an anagram on at least one $(i,i')\in I^2$ with $i$ and $i'$ representing two different $LANG$ numbers.

What smallest $N$ would you select to ensure that your probability of success is greater than $0.26$?

Comment: Note that the smallest possible N is 67, not 76, because the anagram of the number (76) - the number itself (67) is positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to present an argument that shows that

> There is no $N$ which yields a probability of $0.26$.

In fact

> The probability won't go above $0.0006$ for any $N$.

Proof

> For two numbers $m > n$, let's first compute the probability, $p_l(m,n)$, that the word for $m$ is the same length as the word for $n$.
>  Obviously if $m > 2n$, $p_l(m,n) = 0$, otherwise $p_l(m,n) = \frac{2n+1-m}{(m+1)(n+1)} $, (which comes from looking at the region of overlap).
>  Now suppose the words for $m$ and $n$ are of the same length. Then what is the probability, $p_a(m,n)$, that the words are anagrams of each other? Well, I have found this to be a tricky computation but we can put an upper bound on it.
>  In particular, let the length of the words be $N$ and suppose $N$ is large. Then the two words are anagrams of each other if they contain the same number of *a*s, *b*s, *c*s, etc. The randomly generated word which would produce the most such anagrams is one which has an equal distribution across the letters - same number of *a*s, *b*s, *c*s, etc - or as close as possible. The number of anagrams of such a word is roughly approximated by $\frac{N!}{\left(\left( \frac{N}{26} \right)!\right)^{26}}$ (note that we can extend the definition of factorial using the gamma function) which is always less than $26^{26}$.
>  The total number of possibly generated words of length $N$ is $26^N$. Hence, putting these together, for large enough $N$, if the words for $m$ and $n$ are of length $N$, we have $$p_a(m,n) < 26^{26-N}$$ In fact, this is also a bound for small $N$ (albeit a very loose one).
>  We can combine the two formulae above to find that the probability, $p_A(m,n)$ that the words for $2n \geq m > n$ are anagrams of each other is bounded as follows $$ p_A(m,n) < \frac{26^{26-m} + 26^{25-m} + 26^{24-m}+\ldots+26^{26-2n}}{(m+1)(n+1)} = \frac{26^{27-m} - 26^{26-2n}}{25(m+1)(n+1)}$$ In particular, when we introduce the word for a new number $m$, the probability that it is an anagram of a previous word, $p_p(m)$ is bounded above as follows $$ p_p(m) < \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{m/2} \frac{26^{27-m} - 26^{26-2(m-k)}}{25(m+1)(m-k+1)} < \frac{m 26^{27-m}}{25(m+1)(m+2)} < \frac{26^{27-m}}{25(m+2)}$$ Using this, we see that the probability, $P(m)$ for any of the words for numbers greater than or equal to $m$ being an anagram of a word for a smaller number is also bounded, that is $$ P(m) < \displaystyle \sum_{k=m}^{\infty} \frac{26^{27-k}}{25(k+2)} < \frac{26^{28-m}}{625(m+2)}$$ We can see that for even reasonably small values, this probability is very small. For example $P(33) \approx 1.34 \times 10^{-11}$ so we'll have to be pretty close to exceeding  $0.26$ by the time we get to the word for $33$.
>  A quick computation shows that the existence of anagrams in the words for the first $32$ numbers is around $0.00056$ so we won't get a probability very much higher than this for any $N$.